# An example of using the 'from' and 'data' keywords?

Tags: powershell, keyword

Thanks to [this](http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2009/01/05/powershell-abcs---k-is-for-keywords.aspx) article, I was able to come up with a script which sorts and displays the keywords PowerShell provides:

```
$bindingFlags = 
    [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor 
    [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Static -bor 
    [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetField

$keywordTokenReader = [System.Type]::GetType("System.Management.Automation.KeywordTokenReader")
$keywords = $keywordTokenReader.InvokeMember("_keywordTokens", $bindingFlags, $null, $null, $null)
$keywords.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Name
```

I was looking at the list and I understand that `class`, `define`, `using` and `var` are reserved keywords, but just out of curiosity, does anybody have an example using the `from` and `data` keywords? I can't seem to find anything.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Use of the `from` keyword results in this:

```
PS H:\> from
The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
At line:1 char:1
```

The help topic `about_language_keywords` is also useful.

Comment: heh, that's my script (from nivot.org)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The help topic `about_Data_Sections` explains the `data` keyword, run:

```
help about_Data_Sections
```

As for the `from` keyword, I think it is just reserved and not yet used.

Comment: Ah, never saw that help section. Thanks.